# Why does my right navigation overlap with my left in Bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using the default nav bar on my website. I have 4 li nav links on the left and 4 li on the right.

The problems that I am having is when I resize my window, the right nav links gets pushed under the left  nav links, before it gets collapsed.

I would like to have it collapsed before it gets pushed below the left menu links.

Does anyone know how I can accomplish that?

Any help would be really appreciated!

Thank you!

```
   <nav class='navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top' role='navigation'>
        <div class='container-fluid'>
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class='navbar-header'>
                <button type='button' class='navbar-toggle collapsed' data-toggle='collapse' data-target='#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1' aria-expanded='false'>
                    <span class='sr-only'>Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class='icon-bar'></span>
                    <span class='icon-bar'></span>
                    <span class='icon-bar'></span>
                </button>

                    <a href="http://localhost/Freelance/home/index?testing=true"><img src="http://localhost/logo.png" alt="" /></a>


        </div><div class='collapse navbar-collapse' id='bs-example-navbar-collapse-1'><ul class='nav navbar-nav navbar-left'><li><a href="http://localhost/Freelance/client/projects/index">View All Projects</a></li><li><a href="http://localhost/Freelance/messages/messagetpl/managetpl/index">Message Templates</a></li><li><a href="http://localhost/Freelance/client/projects/index?section=manage_hired_freelancers">Manage Hired Freelancers</a></li></ul>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->

        <ul class='nav navbar-nav navbar-right'><li><a href="http://localhost/Freelance/projcollab/hiredprojects/index">Project Collaboration</a></li><li><a href="http://localhost/Freelance/messages/allmessages/index?m=ufn256HeKFHL1VQ6wWxPB242CiMlMuvjgu%2Fct%2BpjJab0FVxFSh4G8YDwX3Uc7dKxNTCSbxTQgt%2F%2FOCOzvSxXKHWrTwYZTO0KLY3rgyUwwKdJYt9SONqios2Ax5XwAVJh">Inbox</a></li><li><a href="http://localhost/Freelance/#">Contact Us</a></li>
            <li><li class='dropdown'>
            <a class='dropdown-toggle' aria-expanded='false' aria-haspopup='true' role='button' data-toggle='dropdown' href='#'> json2021@gmail.com
            <span class='caret'></span> </a>


        <ul class='dropdown-menu'>
        <li><a href="http://localhost/Freelance/#">Account Settings</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://localhost/Freelance/#">Financial Summary</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://localhost/Freelance/#">Contact us</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://localhost/Freelance/#">Log out</a></li>


        </ul>
    </li>

        </li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
```

Comment: can you share the link where it is hosted?

Comment: I can't because its still in development ;(

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you have provided you are missing a closing `</div>` tag to your (i think) `container-fluid` class and a closing `</nav>` tag (unless you purposely didn't add these?)

Also you have this in your HTML which will cause display issues:

```
        <li>
        <li class='dropdown'>
            <a class='dropdown-toggle'....
```

then at the bottom you close it like this:

```
                </ul>
            </li>
        </li>
```

It seems like you just have an extra `<li>` and `</li>` in there that should be removed. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately the issue is the titles of your links are so long that the given space simply cannot accommodate the them as the viewport is reduced.

If you look at the example I posted it has your original `navbar`, one with a highly reduced font-size **(undesirable, only to illustrate my point)** and one that uses icons to help solve the issue. If you open it into a full-page and start to reduce it you'll see what I mean.

**Possible fixes:**

- Change the link titles to accommodate the space when the viewport
  changes.
- Use more dropdowns.
- Replace some links with icons to save space.

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  #test .navbar-nav li a {
    font-size: 8px;
  }
}
.divider {
  margin: 75px 0;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class='navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top' role='navigation'>
  <div class='container-fluid'>
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class='navbar-header'>
      <button type='button' class='navbar-toggle collapsed' data-toggle='collapse' data-target='#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1' aria-expanded='false'> <span class='sr-only'>Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class='icon-bar'></span>
        <span class='icon-bar'></span>
        <span class='icon-bar'></span>

      </button>
      <a href="http://localhost/Freelance/home/index?testing=true">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50/f00" alt="" />
      </a>

    </div>
    <div class='collapse navbar-collapse' id='bs-example-navbar-collapse-1'>
      <ul class='nav navbar-nav navbar-left'>
        <li><a href="http://localhost/Freelance/client/projects/index">View All Projects</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="http://localhost/Freelance/messages/messagetpl/managetpl/index">Message Templates</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="http://localhost/Freelance/client/projects/index?section=manage_hired_freelancers">Manage Hired Freelancers</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <ul class='nav navbar-nav navbar-right'>
        <li><a href="http://localhost/Freelance/projcollab/hiredprojects/index">Project Collaboration</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="http://localhost/Freelance/messages/allmessages/index?m=ufn256HeKFHL1VQ6wWxPB242CiMlMuvjgu%2Fct%2BpjJab0FVxFSh4G8YDwX3Uc7dKxNTCSbxTQgt%2F%2FOCOzvSxXKHWrTwYZTO0KLY3rgyUwwKdJYt9SONqios2Ax5XwAVJh">Inbox</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="http://localhost/Freelance/#">Contact Us</a>

        </li>
        <li>
          <li class='dropdown'> <a class='dropdown-toggle' aria-expanded='false' aria-haspopup='true' role='button' data-toggle='dropdown' href='#'> json2021@gmail.com
            <span class='caret'></span> </a>

            <ul class='dropdown-menu'>
              <li><a href="http://localhost/Freelance/#">Account Settings</a>

              </li>
              <li><a href="http://localhost/Freelance/#">Financial Summary</a>

              </li>
              <li><a href="http://localhost/Freelance/#">Contact us</a>

              </li>
              <li><a href="http://localhost/Freelance/#">Log out</a>

              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
<div class="divider"></div>
<nav class='navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top' role='navigation'>
  <div class='container-fluid'>
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class='navbar-header'>
      <button type='button' class='navbar-toggle collapsed' data-toggle='collapse' data-target='#bs-example-navbar-collapse-2' aria-expanded='false'> <span class='sr-only'>Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class='icon-bar'></span>
        <span class='icon-bar'></span>
        <span class='icon-bar'></span>

      </button>
      <a href="http://localhost/Freelance/home/index?testing=true">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50/266080" alt="" />
      </a>

    </div>
    <div class='collapse navbar-collapse' id='bs-example-navbar-collapse-2'>
      <ul class='nav navbar-nav navbar-left'>
        <li><a href="http://localhost/Freelance/client/projects/index">View All Projects</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="http://localhost/Freelance/messages/messagetpl/managetpl/index">Message Templates</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="http://localhost/Freelance/client/projects/index?section=manage_hired_freelancers">Manage Hired Freelancers</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <ul class='nav navbar-nav navbar-right'>
        <li><a href="http://localhost/Freelance/projcollab/hiredprojects/index"><i class="fa fa-users"></i></a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="http://localhost/Freelance/messages/allmessages/index?m=ufn256HeKFHL1VQ6wWxPB242CiMlMuvjgu%2Fct%2BpjJab0FVxFSh4G8YDwX3Uc7dKxNTCSbxTQgt%2F%2FOCOzvSxXKHWrTwYZTO0KLY3rgyUwwKdJYt9SONqios2Ax5XwAVJh"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i></a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="http://localhost/Freelance/#"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i></a>

        </li>
        <li class='dropdown'>
          <a class='dropdown-toggle' aria-expanded='false' aria-haspopup='true' role='button' data-toggle='dropdown' href='#'> <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
            <span class='caret'></span> 
          </a>

          <ul class='dropdown-menu'>
            <li><a href="http://localhost/Freelance/#">Account Settings</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="http://localhost/Freelance/#">Financial Summary</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="http://localhost/Freelance/#">Contact us</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="http://localhost/Freelance/#">Log out</a>

            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="divider"></div>
<nav class='navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top' id="test" role='navigation'>
  <div class='container-fluid'>
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class='navbar-header'>
      <button type='button' class='navbar-toggle collapsed' data-toggle='collapse' data-target='#bs-example-navbar-collapse-3' aria-expanded='false'> <span class='sr-only'>Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class='icon-bar'></span>
        <span class='icon-bar'></span>
        <span class='icon-bar'></span>

      </button>
      <a href="http://localhost/Freelance/home/index?testing=true">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50/000" alt="" />
      </a>

    </div>
    <div class='collapse navbar-collapse' id='bs-example-navbar-collapse-3'>
      <ul class='nav navbar-nav navbar-left'>
        <li><a href="http://localhost/Freelance/client/projects/index">View All Projects</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="http://localhost/Freelance/messages/messagetpl/managetpl/index">Message Templates</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="http://localhost/Freelance/client/projects/index?section=manage_hired_freelancers">Manage Hired Freelancers</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <ul class='nav navbar-nav navbar-right'>
        <li><a href="http://localhost/Freelance/projcollab/hiredprojects/index">Project Collaboration</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="http://localhost/Freelance/messages/allmessages/index?m=ufn256HeKFHL1VQ6wWxPB242CiMlMuvjgu%2Fct%2BpjJab0FVxFSh4G8YDwX3Uc7dKxNTCSbxTQgt%2F%2FOCOzvSxXKHWrTwYZTO0KLY3rgyUwwKdJYt9SONqios2Ax5XwAVJh">Inbox</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="http://localhost/Freelance/#">Contact Us</a>

        </li>
        <li>
          <li class='dropdown'> <a class='dropdown-toggle' aria-expanded='false' aria-haspopup='true' role='button' data-toggle='dropdown' href='#'> json2021@gmail.com
            <span class='caret'></span> </a>

            <ul class='dropdown-menu'>
              <li><a href="http://localhost/Freelance/#">Account Settings</a>

              </li>
              <li><a href="http://localhost/Freelance/#">Financial Summary</a>

              </li>
              <li><a href="http://localhost/Freelance/#">Contact us</a>

              </li>
              <li><a href="http://localhost/Freelance/#">Log out</a>

              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```